# Popup window isnt fully loaded on first open

Tags: android, android-listview, android-popupwindow

I'm making my android app and got stucked with this problem: when i open popup window for the first time(see picture 1) after fragment is loaded, it seems like its not fully loaded: i cant scroll listview, layout under the listview has wrong background color. But when i close it and open again - everything is ok(see picture 2). How can i fix this?

Hope you can help me.
Best regards, Andrey.

[pic1](http://rghost.net/59893325/image.png) [pic2](http://rghost.net/59893342/image.png)

Comment: Could you post the part of your code that implements the popup?

Comment: Since its big, here is [link](http://rghost.net/private/59893492/80e1010c8dd2aaa86b204132ee5b2946) to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call initiatePopupWindow() in onStart method